# We are going to pick up your mummy at twelve

Tags: grammaticality, usage

I sent my wife to company.
My child asked his mother back in the car.

> Mummy has to work. **We are going to pick up your mummy at twelve.**

Does it sound grammatically correct and natural?

Comment: I agree with Cantalouping. But just in case you wonder why we say "pick her up" not "pick up her", the reason is that "her" is a form of pronoun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context it sounds grammatically correct. Repeating a name in the second sentence would normally be a bit redundant, but with children names are often repeated in conversation for clarity.

Some other ways you could write the sentence include these:

> "Mummy has to work. We are going to pick **her up** at twelve."

If the child refers to his mother as Mummy normally, you could also say:

> "Mummy has to work. We are going to pick up **Mummy** at twelve."

Answer (score 1):

We are going to pick up your mommy/mummy at twelve.

You can also use the adverb or particle "up" of the phrasal verb pick up after the noun phrase "your mummy" as follows, though it's less common:

We are going to pick your mummy up at twelve.

However, as we referring back to the noun mommy, we should use the pronoun her instead of "your mommy", and in case of a pronoun we always use the particle of a phrasal verb  after the pronoun. So we should say:

We are going to pick her up, not to pick up her, at twelve.